# Is there a way I can capture my iPhone screen as a video?

Tags: iphone

I want to be able to capture my iPhone's screen as a video, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Can anyone help guide me on how to best do this *without jailbreak?*

Comment: Without jail break Free in Mac with Yosemite http://stackoverflow.com/a/37874622/3172518

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This answer is outdated*

www.iphonevideorecorder.com. There's a free trial I think, but after that you'd need to buy it. And you need to jailbreak your iphone.

Comment: That's not what you want. In Cydia, if you Jailbreak, there will soon be a paid application by Ryan Petrich (member of this site: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4007/rpetrich ) which is called "Display Recorder", and will get you a /much/ better video.

Comment: That's just a video recording tool for old iphones that didn't have it built-in. He was asking for something else...

Comment: If you're creating iPhone apps, you probably don't want to jailbreak your phone.

Comment: @OdedBenDov: No, it's not. You're thinking of something else. This was a screen recording app.

Comment: @Vargen: I wrote this answer a long time ago, when it did make sense to many people, including myself, to jailbreak. Now I would say it is a waste of time, and for screen recording, there is of course AirPlay, so this answer shouldn't be the accepted one anymore.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my solution in a nutshell:

In recent years, when needing to produce moving visual content from the interface of an iOS app, I would require the developer provide a compiling of the app designed for the Simulator, (must be separately compiled because the apps are, by default compiled to run on the iPhone's ARM processor, whereas the Simulator runs on the Mac's Intel processor). This would then be screen captured on the Mac with something like Snapz Pro, Screenflow or something similar.

Beyond that, typical solutions required jailbreaking the device and installing a screen capture application sourced from the Cydia Store.

With the introduction of the iPad 2, Apple enabled full interface mirrored video output via either an authorized dock connector to HDMI dongle, or a dock connector to VGA dongle. (Note: Apple's composite and component options do not port mirrored content.) While the typical intent for these output mechanisms are to display the interface content to an external projector or High Definition Television, it is possible to record this mirrored content with a device capable of recording or transcoding content from such an incoming source. This option was also made possible with the introduction of the iPhone 4S. Quite often, recording this video content is done with HDMI capture cards installed on the capturing computer, such as those produced by Black Magic or AJA, among others. This is, or course limited to using computers that are capable of having such a capture card installed. Other options may include some HDMI record-enabled DVR devices (though many detect and disable such options) or firewire-based transcoding devices (like the Grass Valley ADVC-HD50, which I use).

Since getting the iPad 2 earlier this year, I have been using the Grass Valley ADVC HD50 to capture iOS screen motion from dock connected HDMI to a HDV compatible video capture application on my Mac. It has thus far worked flawlessly.

Here is an example from a video I recorded showing such captured content from both the iPHone 4S and the iPad 2.

http://youtu.be/k7jlPx8NAmw

However, now that Apple has enabled wireless iOS mirroring via Airplay in iOS 5, I find it is now much more convenient to connect an Apple TV device to the Grass Vally ADVC HD50, and capture the iOS interface screen recording wirelessly.

Here is a recent short video example in which the iPhone 4S interface was captured wirelessly via Airplay mirroring.

http://youtu.be/UKsixjcCXdI

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

As others have suggested, AirPlay mirroring is the way to go. To mirror directly to your computer use an AirPlay server like http://www.airserverapp.com/. Then, since it's showing up directly on your computer you can capture it using the built-in Quicktime app (File > New Screen Recording). Works great!

Comment: Please aware Ben some Internets please for recommending AirServer.  Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Another AirPlay option that has recording built-in (I haven't tried this one myself): http://reflectorapp.com

Comment: I just tried Reflector. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use **[Lookback](http://lookback.io)**. It records your screen, face, voice and all gestures, and uploads them to your account on the web.

Here's a demo: https://lookback.io/watch/JK354d5jcEpA7CNkE

Answer (score 8):

I made a plugin for the simulator that does just this. You can find it at [my blog](http://thinkultimate.com/2009/10/iphone-screen-capture/).

It actually records the screen. It does not rely on another screen capture program like iShowU.

It will install icons for the default apps and change the carrier text to look like a real device.

Answer (score 8):

Loren Brichter the developer of Tweetie2 wrote this little app called SimFinger to make iphone screencasts top notch!

http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/

Love apps that make amateurs look like pros :)

Comment: Seems to be outdated as the server blog.atebits.com is down and atebits.com doesn't show a blog at all.

Comment: https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger

Answer (score 4):

Short of using a video camera, no.

Many youtube videos for demonstrating iPhone applications are made with a screen grabber application (such as iShowU, ScreenFlow, or Snapz Pro) and the simulator. Be aware that the speed of response in the simulator can be dramatically different than a device - so it's possible to get effects (and miss) with the simulator you'll never see on a device. In particular, default animations can flash by in the simulator, where they just look quick on a device.

Comment: "Short of using a video camera, no.": wrong, see my answer.

Comment: having a similiar problem myself with the speed of video capture. Why do you say that there is no other solution? is there really no way to channel to some tvout to a video file?

Answer (score 3):

using ScreenCaptureView class we can capture the iphone screen as video.The source code is available [here](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673).The recorded video is saved in a NSUrl,outputURL.Use that NSUrl in a method like below to play the recorded video,

```
    -(void)playvideo
{

  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:outputURL ];
       [player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

[player setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];   

[player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

 [player setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

 [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

[player play];

[self addSubview:player.view];

}
```

call this method before releasing NSUrl in completeRecordingSession method ..it will replay what you did in the iphone screen as a video.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the video-out and capture that somehow with a firewire or sumthing.. 
The class **MPTVOutWindow** can help you out! Here's a nice sample of that!

**http://iphone-developers-nc.googlegroups.com/web/UIApplication_TVOut.m**

Comment: and yeah. here's some more resource on that one.
http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3

Answer (score 1):

I used [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) to record the Simulator, and zoomed it and added static images as necessary.  I then embedded the movie in an iPhone frame on my website.  Turned out okay.  See the [Tweeps](http://www.dejal.com/tweeps/iphone/) page for the result.

Answer (score 1):

i guess it is so obvious now that no one has posted this but for the noobs.... note: iPhone 4S only

just airplay to an apple tv and video mirror then output the atv to a device that can record - like tivo, dvr etc. you can also use a video out cable on the iPad [1 and 2] now

not sure if the cable works on the iPhone 4S as I havent tested that myself

its clunky but there is no other way i can see atm.

Answer (score 0):

I've continued to research this item myself, and it does appear to remain beyond us at this point.

I even tried buying a [Apple Composite AV Cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB129LL/A), but it doesn't capture screen, just video playing like YouTube, etc.

So I decided to go with the iShowU path and that has worked out well so far.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

For a nice looking screencast, have a look at [SimFinger](http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/). You will still need a screen recoder such as [Snapz Pro](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who is still looking for solutions:

The RecordMyScreen jailbreak app is opensourced and works fine even on non-jailbreak devices if we have the developer license. You can have a look at the source: https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen

Answer (score -4):

I dont believe this is possible.
Your best bet is to get something like iShowU and capture from the simulator.

Comment: This is possible man...Get my answer above...