# How can you save Cocos2D window output as Video?

Tags: video, cocos2d-iphone, mpeg

I am considering using the excellent looking Cocos2d for a motion graphics project.
However, Cocos2d is intended for games, rather than producing an MPEG stream.

Is it possible to save the output from a Cocos2d script to a MOV or MPG file?
Ideally this needs to be done in a direct manner, not using a screen capture
as this would not meet the requirements of the project.

Hopefully there are some cocos2d gurus out there :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a different library which is more "export" friendly.
Not exactly the same as Cocos2D. *Node Box* is a Python based motion graphics library. Admittedly it's useless for games, but good for drawing and motion graphics (which is what I wanted to use Cocos2d for anyway!)

http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home

Answer (score 1):

There are some options like the one posted on this question: [Is there a way I can capture my iPhone screen as a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video) but for that you have to jailbreak your device.

On this link (http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3), you can check a way to send the video of the device to you computer, so you can record it.

In my opinion, depending on how is your project, you could use something like iSimulator, to use the device to send input commands to the simulator and use a program to record the screen.

Let me know if it helps you.

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I was more interested in the desktop version of Cocos2D not the iPhone Cocos2D library. Specifically, I would like to be able to define Cocos2d routines (this part I can figure out using Python) and then render them into MPEG video on a server. Any ideas? :D

Comment: Well, the idea is the same, for iPhone and Desktop. what is the problem of using a screen recorder?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I need something that can run in a server environment. Thx