# how to create a video for iPod touch app video ?

Tags: xcode, video, ios-simulator, video-capture, ipod-touch

for ppt presentation i want to create video for ipod touch app.

is their any possibility to create video

1. from Xcode using simulator
2. or directly from device
3. or any other possibility

thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean create video of your app functioning to present in a ppt?  Or what do you mean "create video for ipod touch app?"

Comment: @HansGruber yes i want to create video for my app functioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [Is there a way I can capture my iPhone screen as a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video)

This post describes many ways to capture video.  It looks like there isn't a completely intuitive way to record the video, but this post lists some of the options others have used for their applications.