# Turn off HDCP copyright flag for the purposes of recording trailer

Tags: iphone, ios5, hdmi

I've just acquired a HDMI recorder card, and I'm trying to digitally capture the output from my game using the HDMI out from a iPhone 4S.

Problem is software keeps complaining that the content is copyrighted and cannot record.

Is there a way I can setup the HDMI stream so that inside my game the HDCP copy flag isn't on ?

Even looking forward letting my costumers record their gaming sessions seems like a good idea, I think that's something that I would like to permit.

Comment: See [this stackoverflow discussion][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video

Comment: nope, doesn't help. I already have a capture card an HDMI cable and a 4S. I can capture the resulting video on the on the screen using ishowu or something, what I can't do is capture directly, achieving flicker free highest digitally possible movie.

Comment: drat... oh well, was worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't turn off HDCP. That protection standard was founded on the basis that anything with HDCP enabled should never be recorded.

I have a monitor (a new samsung) at home I can't use because its not HDCP compatible, and newer video cards require it :(

Comment: I dont't ask how to turn off HDCP. HDCP has copyright flag, content witn the flag off can be recorded.

Comment: No, you can't. If it would have been such easy to remove this flag, they wouldn't have spent that much of money into it. Once you define that your content is HDCP encrypted, it is just encrypted as its name implies. The only way to get it back is to decrypt, which is what HDCP requires.

Comment: @Dundar I think you're missing the point - OP is asking how to not enable encryption on the source content which he owns.