# Taking Video of IOS Game

Tags: ios, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way I can capture my iPhone screen as a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video)

I know that you can take screenshots from the organizer in xcode. I looked in the organizer but couldn't find a feature similar to this that took a video. Is there any way to capture gameplay videos on ios devices without actually videotaping the screen?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I did look through all similar questions and google searched it and nothing came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a program to make your Mac into an Airplay compatible device, such as:
http://www.reflectionapp.com/

This way you can mirror the device on the Mac screen, and use a program such as Quicktime to record the window.

Comment: If you wait just a bit longer for Mountain Lion, AirPlay from iOS devices to Mountain Lion will be built into OS X. It does require a 2011+ Mac and either an iPhone 4S or iPad 2+ though.