# Is it possible to capture video of an iPod without jailbreaking? Is it possible to add code snippets to my App to send video data to AirServer?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video) that suggests to use AirServer to capture video from iPhone. Unfortunately AirServer doesn't support iPods (even though I have a 4th gen iPod running iOS 5.0). Is there a way via software or should I get my iPod to connect to a TV and record it there? I have seen that there are some good cables to connect iPod to TV but I lost the link and now can find only suggestion that explains how to do it on jailbroken iPods.. (which I don't want to do).

EDIT (For the one that closed the topic): is there any code snippet that I can use to send the video data from my app to AirServer?