# Is it possible to enable a Cocos2d app to mirror display on HDMI-AirServer-Apple TV?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ipod, hdmi, apple-tv

AirServer, AppleTV support only certain iPhones models and iPads. However, iPod touch 4th generation is supported but only for certain applications (e.g. YouTube).

I had asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351714/is-it-possible-to-capture-video-of-an-ipod-without-jailbreaking-is-it-possible) which has been closed, and has been voted for re-open. With this question I would like to focus on the programming side of the question.

Is it possible to add some code to my **iPod touch 4** Cocos2D app to **enable the App mirrowing**?

I found some reference and UIScreen has the [mirrored property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) but I am a bit confused because **the Apple store assitant said that iPod 4 generation has a different chip that doesn't allow the mirrowing**. I thought that this was not true because is actually possible to mirrow Youtube, as well as by jailbraking the iPod 4 it should be possible too.

I am in the hunt of a **tutorial-guide to enable this for my Cocos2D iPod 4 app**. With iPhone 4S onwards this should be possible without adding any code but the issue that I want to solve is for iPod 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airplay mirroring is an iOS 5 feature and available when the user selects it. This feature is not available on iPod Touch 4.

To connect to Apple TV [refer to this guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5209) where the minimum requirements (iPhone 4S, iPad 2) are also listed.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a software or hardware reason? Will it be different for iPod touch 5?

Comment: I'm not involved in the development of Apple devices, so I don't know. If I were, I couldn't say. :)